# Is a surjective continuous map that makes the same identifications with a quotient map is a quotient map?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X, Y, Z$ be spaces, $q : X \to Y$ a quotient map, and $p : X \to Z $ a surjective continuous map. Suppose $q(x)=q(x')$ iff $p(x)=p(x')$, for all $x, x' \in X$. I hope that $p$ is also a quotient map and that $Y, Z$ are homeomorphic, but I do I have to show this?

I know that $p$ induces a continuous bijection $f : Y \to Z$ such that $f \circ q=p$, but I can't show that $f$ is a homeomorphism

Comment: Take $U\subseteq Z$ open. Then $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, and because $q$ is a quotient map, $q(p^{-1}(U))$ is open in $Y$. But $q(p^{-1}(U)) = f^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That shows that $f$ is continuous, which I already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately. Consider $X=Y=Z$ as sets. Let $p=q=\text{id}$ but $X=Y$ both are discrete while $Z$ is not. Note how much stronger conditions these maps satisfy: $q$ is a homeomorphism, $p$ is a bijection and $p(x)=q(x)$.